# reverse mathematics of the Lebesgue measurability of analytic sets

Tags: lo.logic, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory, reverse-math

Can the fact that all analytic sets are Lebesgue measurable be proven in $Z_2$, or in some weak subsystem such as $\Pi^1_1\text{-CA}_0$? Conversely, can certain set existence axioms be derived from the assumption that all analytic sets are Lebesgue measurable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe $\Delta^1_2$-CA$_0$ does indeed suffice; however, I don't see a way to pull this down to $\Pi^1_1$-CA$_0$.

*This is contrary to my previous claim; my error was with respect to the strength of the relevant choice principle.*

---

Let me briefly outline the classical proof:

- First, we show a version of Lebesgue regularity: that for any analytic set $A$, the outer measure of $A$ exists and that there is a $G_\delta$ (and hence measurable) set $B$ with $A\subseteq B\subseteq cl(A)$ and $m(X)=0$ for all measurable $X\subseteq B\setminus A$.
- Next, let $A$ be an analytic set. Fixing a continuous function $f$ whose image is $A$, we let $A_\sigma$ be the image of $f$ restricted to the set of reals beginning with $\sigma$ (for $\sigma\in\omega^{<\omega}$) and we let $B_\sigma$ be the set corresponding to $A_\sigma$ per the bulletpoint above.
- Looking to the $B_\sigma$s for a moment, it's not hard to show that for all $\sigma\in\omega^{<\omega}$, the set $$Z_\sigma:=B_\sigma\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\omega}B_{\sigma n}$$ is measurable and is contained in $B_\sigma\setminus A_\sigma$. But from this it follows that $Z_\sigma$ is null.
- Elementary set-juggling shows that $$B\setminus A\subseteq\bigcup_{\sigma\in\omega^{<\omega}}Z_\sigma.$$ Since the union of countably many null sets is null, we have that $B\setminus A$ is measurable; since $B$ is measurable, this implies that $A$ is also measurable, and so we're done.

---

Now, translating this into the context of reverse mathematics, we run into three important points:

- We need to talk about *codes* for sets of reals, rather than sets of reals themselves. Luckily, we're basically looking here at the first couple levels of the Borel hierarchy and at analytic sets, so we have reasonable coding notions.
- We need to be able to do basic "set-juggling" with these codes. But this winds up being straightforward.
- Finally, we need to be able to prove basic facts about Lebesgue measure: in particular, that the measurable (coded) sets are closed under countable Boolean combinations and that the union of countably many null sets is null. **This is the difficult bit:** it involves choosing "nearly optimal" covers in a concrete way: e.g. to show that $\bigcup_{n\in\omega} X_n$ is null if each $X_n$ is null, we really want a sequence $(\mathcal{O}_{n,k})_{n,k\in\omega}$ such that $\mathcal{O}_{n,k}$ is an open cover of $X_n$ with total measure ${1\over k+1}$. When the $X_n$s are given uniformly by analytic codes - as in our situation here - the set of legal choices for $\mathcal{O}_{n,k}$ is a nonempty $\Pi^1_1$ set uniformly in $n,k$.

So the question now is: how strong is $\Pi^1_1$ choice? Unfortunately (and contra my original claim) it turns out that it is rather strong indeed. In fact, it is equivalent to $\Delta^1_2$-CA$_0$; this follows from Theorem VII.$6.9(1)$, page $298$, in Simpson's book together with Carl's observation that $\Pi^1_1$-choice is equivalent to $\Sigma^1_2$-choice.

So the above argument gives a proof of the result in a weak-but-not-too-weak subsystem of Z$_2$.

Comment: $\Pi^1_1$-choice was the only thing outside of ATR$_0$ that proof uses, right? Is $\text{ATR}_0+\Pi^1_1\text{-choice}$ strictly weaker than $\Pi^1_1\text{-CA}_0$?

Comment: @AlexMennen Yes, that's right (although I can't rule out the possibility of avoiding $\Pi^1_1$-AC via cleverness, of course). As to your second question, I *think* the answer is yes, but annoyingly I can't find any sources on it! I'll do a more serious literature dive tomorrow (or, y'know, try it myself).

Comment: @CarlMummert Crud, you're right - and $\Sigma^1_2$ choice is stronger than $\Pi^1_1$-CA$_0$. Edited!

Comment: This is easy to miss in that section of SOSOA. It never mentions any $\Pi$ choice principles, but it mentions tangentially that $\Sigma^1_0$ choice is equivalent to $\Sigma^1_1$ choice.

Comment: Why $\Pi^1_1$-CA is not sufficient? You just need to prove that every $\Pi^1_1$-set is measurable. To prove this, you need to prove that the set $\omega_1^x=\omega_1^{CK}$ has measure 1 and then prove every Borel set is measurable.

Comment: @喻良 Yes, that's definitely better (and hadn't occurred to me) - if you post it as an answer, I'll upvote it (and the OP should accept it). I want to leave my answer mostly as-is, though, since checking the strength needed to carry out the usual proof is worthwhile in itself even if very suboptimal.

Comment: @喻良, I do not understand this argument.

Comment: I think all the details are already there. I am more interested in the relationship between the measurability of analytic sets and ATR_0. It seems the question is related to an open question in higher randomness theory.

Comment: It might be equivalent to $\Pi^1_1-CA_0$, since there is a $\Pi^1_1$-closed set of which the measure is hyperarithmetically above hyperjump.

Comment: I do not understand what the fact that $\{x:\omega_1^x=\omega_1^{CK}\}$ has measure 1 has to do with analytic sets being measurable.

Comment: Incidentally, I find it really surprising that the biggest obstacle in Noah's proof is showing countable additivity for measures of Borel sets. I had naively assumed this was provable in ATR$_0$.

Comment: @AlexMennen There is a natural "rank" function $e_A:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \omega_1\cup\{\infty\}$ associated to a $\Pi^1_1$ set $A$, given by sending $r$ to the rank of the tree $T_r$ corresponding to the question "$r\in A?$" (where this rank is $\infty$ iff $r\not\in A$). The key point now is that we always have $$e_A(r)<\infty\iff e_A(r)<\omega_1^{CK}(r),$$ and hence for measure-$1$ many $r$s we have $r\in A\iff e_A(r)<\infty\iff e_A(r)<\omega_1^{CK}$. The set $\{r: e_A(r)<\omega_1^{CK}\}$ is Borel, hence measurable.

Comment: There is a generalized recursion theory connection here. The rank function provides a way to think of $\Pi^1_1$-ness as an analogue of c.e.-ness, where computations take *ordinal* time instead of *natural number* time ($r$ enters $A$ at stage $e_A(r)$). This analogy works *extremely* sharply and simply when we're talking about sets of *naturals* - $X\subseteq\omega$ is $\Pi^1_1$ iff $X$ is $\Sigma_1$-definable in $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$, that is, iff $X$ is *$\omega_1^{CK}$-recursively enumerable* - but it also works when we look at sets of reals, and that's how it's being deployed here.

Comment: @喻良 I strongly disagree with "all the details are already there" - the relevance of the map $x\mapsto\omega_1^x$ to coanalytic sets is a quick but deep fact in my opinion (if we just think of coanalytic sets as complements of images of continuous maps it's not at all clear that there should be any connection). Meanwhile, what is the open question you mention?

Comment: @AlexMennen In more detail, let me describe the map $e_A$, since it's really doing all the conceptual heavy lifting (ok, that and the measure fact mentioned, which I haven't even sketched a proof for). Working in Baire space for simplicity, it's not hard to show that $A\subseteq\omega^\omega$ is $\Pi^1_1$ iff there is a tree $T\subseteq(\omega\times\omega)^{<\omega}$ such that for all $r\in\omega^\omega$, $r$ is **not** in $A$ iff it is "one half of" a path through $T$ (that is, for some $s\in\omega^\omega$ we have $((r(0), s(0)),...,(r(n), s(n)))\in T$ for all $n$). (cont'd)

Comment: Now given a real $r$, let $T_r\subseteq\omega^{<\omega}$ be the "$r$-piece" of $T$: $$T_r=\{(a_0,...,a_n): ((a_0, r(0)),...,(a_n, r(n)))\in T\}.$$ Switching sides, we have that $r$ **is** in $A$ iff $T_r$ is well-founded. Now $T_r$ is computable from $r$ together with a code for $A$; in particular, if $A$ is lightface then $T_r$ is computable from $r$ and hence the rank of $T_r$ (if it is well-founded) is an ordinal $<\omega_1^{CK}(r)$. *(In my initial comment, I omitted the crucial remark: "assume WLOG that $A$ is lightface." Otherwise we have to relativize the claim.)* That gives us the map!

Comment: Now why does $\{x: \omega_1^{CK}=\omega_1^{CK}(x)\}$ have full measure? *I write "$\omega_1^{CK}(x)$" instead of "$\omega_1^x$," but that's a very minority notation; I do think it's better, though.* This winds up being a forcing argument, and is covered in [chapter IV of Sacks' book](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235422636).